# In Meteor, where can I find errors related to typos in functions?

Tags: javascript, meteor

newbie in Meteor here.

I was walking through the simple to-do list in the Meteor tutorial (React version) and I made a typo in the following section:

```
Tasks.insert({
  text,
  createdAt: new Date(), // current time
  owner: Meteor.userID(),
  username: Meteor.user().username,
});
```

In this case I got my capitalization wrong and the Meteor function should have been `Meteor.userId()`. However, no errors were thrown up in the terminal window even though the function called should have been undefined. It took me a long time to find this and I'm worrying that for larger applications such errors will be difficult to find if no errors are reported.

Could more experienced users share with me why Meteor is designed not to report the typo as an error, and perhaps provide some tips on finding such errors in the future?

Comment: JavaScript is a difficult language to be really reference strict on, the only real way to check is to run code with a debugger attached. However, you can reduce the chance that things like this happen by using an IDE which understands the syntax to discover references, especially if it can make use of a linter. e.g. I have an [`.eslintrc.json`](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=eslint) file I use which also makes use of [`eslint-plugin-meteor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-meteor). It's always good to use a linter.

Comment: to follow up on @PaulS. comment, WebStorm does a good job out of the box with JS. but adding a linter is even better. also: is this your first exposure to JS? what you're seeing is less a Meteor thing and more a "no compile-time checking" thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two places where you can see runtime errors in Meteor.

1. If the code lives on the client side then you will see errors in the javascript console which is part of your browser's dev tools.
2. If your code lives on the server side then you will find the error messages in the terminal window where you ran meteor.

If your code can be called from either side then you'll find the error on the side where the error occurred.

Comment: `Meteor.userID` will return `undefined` but `Meteor.userID()` will error directly with `Meteor.userID is not a function` and the insert won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a javascript issue than Meteor. Being essentially a runtime dynamic language, JS has no way of knowing, at compile time, that Meteor.UserID won't be defined at the time of execution. So you won't get the error until that segment of code actually runs.

One way to deal with this is to adopt test-driven development techniques, where you write tests as you code, so that you ensure that each piece of code is tested in a controlled runtime environment (the test environment). If you had a unit test for that function, it would have immediately flagged the error.

Meteor's testing abilities are still a little clunky but a lot better with the latest versions. You can read about their recommended practices here: https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html